# foreach results in endless loop

Tags: php, session, foreach

I have an array stored in $_SESSION:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['session_article']);

//result:
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
        ["amount"]=> int(2) 
    } 
    [1]=> array(2) { 
        ["id"]=> string(2) "13" 
        ["amount"]=> int(1) 
    } 
}
```

If I do:

```
for($artKey = 0;$artKey < count($_SESSION['session_article']);$artKey++){
    $cartArt = $_SESSION['session_article'][$artKey];

    //stuff that doesn't affect key or value
}
```

everything is fine ...but if I do:

```
foreach($_SESSION['session_article'] as $artKey => $cartArt){
    //stuff that doesn't affect key or value
}
```

the page won't stop to load (infinite loading, like the foreach never terminates)

Comment: The code is fine- do you have more code you aren't showing here?

Comment: Have you tried echoing something in the `foreach` loop to see what exactly it is doing? Just get it to echo the `$artKey` value. Then when you load it you should get some idea of why it's running an endless loop.

Comment: Have you actually removed the `//stuff that doesn't affect key or value` to ensure it doesn't affect it, or are you just guessing?

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://codepad.org/0wQtF9qg

Answer (score 0):

I would like to you know that the computer is not a dumb machine, so whenever you do not get the right result then its not the computers problem, it is in how you code.

So lets take a look at your code first you `var_dump($_SESSION['session_article'])` you got an array with two elements each being an associative array. Now observe that this is an array of arrays so you code in scenario 2 is wrong.

If it were to be just a single array say `$myArray = ['Simon', 'Peter', 'You']` then this woul have worked fine (note I used the short array syntax here you can use array() if you prefer). But the problem is you have multidimensional Arrays so you could should be

`foreach($_SESSION['session_article'], list($a,))
 {
   //stuffs here 
 }`

or better walk through the $_SESSION['session_article'] as an associative array like so

```
$myArray = $_SESSION['session_article']
$field = count($myArray, COUNT_RECURSIVE - (int)2)
for ($record = 0; $record < $myArray.length; $record++) {
 //record number

  for ($field = 0; $field < $field ; $field++) {
    //combine record and field here 
  }

}
```

Hope I could lend a helping hand?
Please checkout
http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

They really have a good doc, just take you time.

Comment: You are aware that the code is in PHP, right? - there is no such thing as $myArray.length, also the access to $cartArt would be $cartArt["id"] / $cartArt["amount"], which is perfectly fine. in PHP, both methods should work fine

Comment: thanks for the correction - just the life of an upcoming geek